# Meaning of "working out" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following passage is by John D. Rockefeller Jr, as quoted in Peter Singer's *A Darwinian Left*:

> The growth of a large business is merely a survival of the fittest. . . The American Beauty rose can be produced in the splendor and fragrance which bring cheer to its beholder only by sacrificing the early buds which grow around it. This is not an evil tendency in business. It is merely the **working out** of a law of nature and a law of God.

(emphasis by me)

I'm not sure about the meaning of "working out" here.

One possibility is that it is derived from the verb *to work out* [meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/working%20out) *to bring about by labor and exertion*.

Comment: See definition1 at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/work_out)

Comment: Try to see it my way.  Do I have to keep on talking till I can't go on?  While you see it your way, run the risk of knowing that our love may soon be gone.  We can work it out.  We can work it out.

Answer (score 1):

**work out**, a phrasal verb  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/work-out)

> to result in some way

As in your question:

> It is merely the result, in some way, of the law of nature and a law
>   of God.

**Working out** meaning it happens in a certain way, leading to, producing, or resulting in a certain outcome, often well.